# VMware terminology & home usage

Tags: vmware

Some while ago, I dabbled in VMware virtualization. It must have been around version 4 or 5 of the Workstation product, and it was never more than an idle curiosity - meaning that I know next to nothing about VMware in my current situation.

I am building a hardware firewall (based on something like pfSense), and recently I had the idea to virtualize the instance so I can use the box for other things as well.

My predicament is figuring out how the actual virtualization works, in terms of what products perform what role. If anyone could help me out either with their own words or relevant links, I'd be grateful. I've scoured google for a few days now, but I am not much wiser than when I started:

What is ESXi, in comparison to vSphere? What does one do that the other doesn't, and which of them do I need in order to host VMs on bare metal?

Comment: Why does this question even contain vulgar language?  You are going to need to modify your question, so you ask a specific question, because after reading the question three times I have no idea what you want to know.

Comment: I've shortened it. Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: vSphere is simple a tool to configure ESXi virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean vSphere is required or simply an ease-of-use product?

Comment: Its the only tool that I know that supports ESXi virtual machines, since both are proprietary tools, there are similar solutions like ESXi though.

Comment: "I am building a hardware firewall (based on something like pfSense), and recently I had the idea to virtualize the instance so I can use the box for other things as well." ESXi is full blown hypervisor so you can use the box for other things as long as they too are virtual. This is very different to Workstation that runs on top of another OS (e.g. Windows). Which one are you interested in as this will vastly change your requirements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXi is the product: Bare metal hypervisor.
It comes in 2 flavors: The full product, which consist of ESXi + vCenter (expensive) and ESXi standalone, which is free but has some limitations.

vSphere is the front-end application to manage VMware infrastructure, regardless of which variant of ESXi you are using. To make matters confusing: Sometimes, even by VMware themselves, vSphere is used as the name for the whole VMware software suite.
ESX and ESXi are often used interchangeably which further adds to the confusion.
Offically, starting as of version 5.0, ESXi is the only name for the entire product (with or without vCenter), but a lot of documentation (even from VMWare themselves) still uses ESX as the name for the entire product and ESXi for just the hypervisor.

Comment: You mention ESXi is free but don't indicate what the full product is exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, and what I wrote isn't entirely correct either. Will amend.

Comment: @Ramhound Even VMWare is sloppy with the naming. I've got a ESXi 6.0 brochure in front of me that alternates between ESX and ESX-i 5 times on the first page alone. No wonder people get confused.